# chi-square test Matlab for vectors with different length

Tags: matlab, chi-squared

I have to vectors of different size.
Each element represents a subject that can belong to one of the four groups (1=white, 2=black, 3=asian, 4=hispanic).

```
A = [1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 3 4];
B = [2 1 1 1 2 3 4 1 4 1 4 4 4];
```

For example in the A group there are

```
5 white subjects
3 black subjects
1 asian subject
1 hispanic subject
```

How can I determine whether the two groups are statistically different regarding their composition? Is there a Matlab function (chi-square test) that I can use?
How should I use it?

**Please note that the two groups have different length.**

Comment: It doesn't matter if your vectors are different length, you're binning them the same (4 groups).

Comment: Can you please tell me how to perform the chi-square test with my input?

Answer (score 0):

First off, your data sets are two different lengths because they're arrays that represent people. What you want to be comparing is the quantity of each race.

```
Races: [White Black Asian Hispanic rando? rando? rando?]
A: [5 3 1 1 0 0 0];
B: [5 2 1 3 0 1 1];
```

I'm not sure what the values 6 and 7 represent, but if they're just another race, then you would want to keep your arrays consistent. Creating a function to count up the number of times an integer in an array isn't hard.

There are functions pre-written in Matlab, but I personally am not familiar with them. http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/chi2gof.html

You can always write your own function, which would take the Chi-Squared test formula. Just use a for loop that iterates through each value of your vectors A and B, where B is your observed?

Chi = (sum of all (A[i]^2-B[i]^2)/B[i])^(1/2).

Hope this helps.